# Core Data Objective C update content of Entity

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I am first time asking question here, sorry, but I can not find similar one.
So, I need update data in Entity "City" attribute - @"name".
for Example in my Core Data I already have @"New York", @"Boston".
And by parsing XML I have NSMutableArray *Cities = (@"New York", @"Boston", @"Los Angeles", @"Washington");

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *attributeString = @"name";
    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//save to the TableView
cell.textLabel.text = [[object valueForKey:attributeString] description];
if ((indexPath.row + 1) == numberOfSectionsInTableView && (self.isParsingDone))
        [self.insertNewObjectToCities:nil];
//When coredata updating - tableView is also updating automatically


//Here is just adding new data, but I do not know how to update
- (void)insertNewObjectToCities_translation:(id)sender
{
     NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSString *attributeString = @"name";

if (![[self.parseCities.Cities objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[newManagedObject valueForKey:attributeString]])
{
    [newManagedObject setValue:[self.parseCities.Cities objectAtIndex:i] forKey:attributeString];
    NSLog(@"OBBB %@", [self.parseCities.Cities objectAtIndex:i]);
    NSLog(@"dessss %@", [[newManagedObject valueForKey:attributeString] description]);

    i++;

    if (i==[self.parseCities.Cities count]) 
    {
        i = 0;
        return;
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"valueForKey %@", [newManagedObject valueForKey:attributeString]);
        [self insertNewObjectToCities_translation:nil];
    }
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"else");
    return;
}

// Save the context.
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
    // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update a managed object, you first need to fetch it, make any changes to the fields in the fetched `NSManagedObject`, and then save the context you used to fetch the object. If you call `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` again, it will insert a new managed object every time, even if it already exists in Core Data.

It's quite slow to fetch a single object every time you need to check and see if a new one needs to be added. You might want to cache the objects you currently have loaded (or their unique identifying field) into an `NSArray` or `NSSet` so you can check that for membership, instead.